# Passing Data From One Component to Another React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, components

Hey guys and gals i am trying to pass data from a text field in one component to another component. But the component that calls the text field is called in my Home.tsx file while i need the data from my Search.tsx file ( which also has where the text field is created ) to be sent to my searchResults.tsx file. Hope that makes sense

Here is my Home.tsx

```
import { ChakraProvider, Flex, Heading, IconButton, Input, Spacer, useColorMode, useDisclosure, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Search from "../components/Search";



const Home = () => {
    return(
    <div>
        <Flex>
            <Search></Search>
        </Flex>
       
    </div>
    )

}


export default Home
```

Here is my Search.tsx

```
import { TextField, IconButton} from "@material-ui/core"
import {Router, SearchOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "../App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChakraProvider,Box, color, position } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../images/logo.svg';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    input: {
        color: "blue"
    }
})


const Search = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [displaySearchTerm, setDisplaySearchTerm] = useState("");
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        input: {
          color: "#fcba03",
        },
      }));
      const classes = useStyles(); 

    return(
        
      <div>
            <div className='searchCont' style={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center'}} >
                
                <Logo style={{ height: 150, width: 300, position: "absolute", verticalAlign: "middle", marginTop: 200, left: '40%', backgroundColor: '#1a202c', borderRadius: 10 }} />
                <TextField
                    inputProps={{color: classes.input}}
                    style={{width: 600, display: "flex", position: "absolute", verticalAlign: "middle", backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 5, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 400, marginBottom: 50, left: '32%', marginRight: 200}}
                    margin="normal"
                    className="textField"
                    fullWidth
                    id="standard-bare"
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Search for Domains..."
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                    
                    InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                        <IconButton onClick={() =>{searchTerm}}>
                        <SearchOutlined />
                        </IconButton>
                    ),
                    }}      
                />
            </div>
        </div>
      
        
    )
}

export default Search
```

Here is my searchResults.tsx

```
import { Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import {searchTerm} from "../components/Search";

const SearchResults = () => {
    
    return(
        <div>
            <Flex>
                <Search data={searchTerm} /> //error here

            </Flex>
        </div>

    )
}
export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: Where have you import searchresults in any of the components

Comment: There are two basic ways you can achieve this. Either you have to handle the logic in a parent component where these components are its child. The other option is to use redux and manage the state separately.

Comment: Uh nowhere @Rahul Mohanty

Comment: The parent component being search? @dulaj

Comment: Actually as I understood, you have to use some sort of global state management mechanism for this. I prefer redux.

Answer (score 1):

use Redux as your state management system for this, this will help you read and write states across application without worrying.

You can also try react Context if its a one off issue and you dont wana invest into the redux system and its boiler plate code, but if you face this issue more frequently as your project grows complex use redux.